# how to store data from google spreadsheets to database(:- only the top first row is getting stored to data base

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, hana

```java
public class AccountProjectSheet {

    public AccountProjectDTO spreadsheets() {
        SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("Sheet1");
        AccountProjectDTO accountProjectDTO = new AccountProjectDTO(); //creating an object of AccountProjectDto class to assign values which are coming from spreadsheet
        try {
            //Read Data
            String sheetUrl = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/*******key********(just to maintain privacy)********/default/public/values";

            URL url = new URL(sheetUrl);
            // Get Feed of Spreadsheet url
            ListFeed lf = service.getFeed(url, ListFeed.class);
            //Iterate over feed to get cell value

            for (ListEntry le: lf.getEntries()) {
                CustomElementCollection cec = le.getCustomElements();
                //Pass column name to access it's cell values
                accountProjectDTO.setProjectCode(cec.getValue("projectCode"));
                accountProjectDTO.setProjectName(cec.getValue("projectName"));
                accountProjectDTO.setAccountCode(cec.getValue("accountCode"));
                accountProjectDTO.setAccountName(cec.getValue("accountName"));
                accountProjectDTO.setProjectManagerName(cec.getValue("projectManagerName"));
                accountProjectDTO.setDeliveryManagerName(cec.getValue("deliveryManagerName"));
                accountProjectDTO.setProjectStatus(cec.getValue("projectStatus"));
                accountProjectDTO.setProjectMetricsLink(cec.getValue("projectMatricsLink"));

                return accountProjectDTO;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return accountProjectDTO;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get data from Google Sheets to Hana DB, but only the top first row is getting affected. I want to store all the rows in the spreadsheets

Comment: I suspect Problem in Iterating the for loop , Instead of return a List that you received in ListEntry you are returning  a Single POJO (accountProjectDTO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the code, I assume that you want to get a list of `AccountProjectDTO` in order to further store them in a database. But the method signature is wrong as the method returns only one `AccountProjectDTO`.

You are returning the first `AccountProjectDTO` instead of building the list of all `AccountProjectDTO` and return it.

Schematically, you should replace this :

```
public AccountProjectDTO spreadsheets() {
    SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("Sheet1");
    AccountProjectDTO accountProjectDTO = new AccountProjectDTO(); 
    [...]

        for (ListEntry le: lf.getEntries()) {
            [...]   
            return accountProjectDTO;
        }
```

with that :

```
public List<AccountProjectDTO> spreadsheets() {
    SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("Sheet1");
    List<AccountProjectDTO> result = new ArrayList<>();
    [...]

        for (ListEntry le: lf.getEntries()) {
            AccountProjectDTO accountProjectDTO = new AccountProjectDTO(); 
            [...]   
            result.add(accountProjectDTO);
        }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: tank you very much.